# Dataframe, get sum of range if value within range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am kinda lost here and not sure how to proceed.
Basically I have two dataframes that I read from csv files.

```
data = {'A': [0,11,21,31,41,51,61],
        'B': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]}

data2 = {'Point': [11.5, 18.3, 31.3, 41.2, 51.5, 66.6, 34.7, 12.1, 14.4, 56.8, 54.3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

what I am trying to do is to find if the point in df2 is within the range of column A and B of data and return (A+B) which gets added as another column to df. Example for the first point 11.5, I should get back the result of 11+20 and add to the new column infant of that value

so the output ends up like this

```
Point   :    Returned_Data
11.5             31
18.3             31
31.3             71
and so on
```

The issue I'm running into is merging or combing on range or two DataFrames that have different column and row lengths.
I know how to use np.where to match values but how to do I do it for above, have also tried using bin, but that gives me back the range instead of the value.

```
 range = [0,11,21,31,41,51,61]
 df['Returned_Data'] = pd.cut (x=check[list], bins =range)
```

```
    A   B Returned_Data
0   0  10       (0, 11]
1  11  20      (11, 21]
2  21  30      (21, 31]
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Series of Intervals with [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html), then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
s = (df[['A', 'B']].sum(axis=1)
     .set_axis(pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['A'], df['B']))
     )

out = s.reindex(df2['Point']).reset_index(name='Returned Data')
```

Output:

```
    Point  Returned Data
0    11.5             31
1    18.3             31
2    31.3             71
3    41.2             91
4    51.5            111
5    66.6            131
6    34.7             71
7    12.1             31
8    14.4             31
9    56.8            111
10   54.3            111
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to figure out which range each `Point` value lies in, then sum the beginning and end values from that range:

```py
ranges = df2['Point'].apply(lambda v:np.argmax((df['A'] <= v) & (v <= df['B'])))
df2['Returned Data'] = df.loc[ranges, ['A', 'B']].sum(axis=1).values
```

Output:

```
    Point  Returned Data
0    11.5             31
1    18.3             31
2    31.3             71
3    41.2             91
4    51.5            111
5    66.6            131
6    34.7             71
7    12.1             31
8    14.4             31
9    56.8            111
10   54.3            111
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
interval_ranges = [df['A'].iloc[0]] + df['B'].tolist()
(
    df2.assign(interval=pd.cut(df2['Point'], interval_ranges))
    .merge(
        df.assign(interval=pd.cut(df['B'], interval_ranges))
     )
     .assign(Returned_Data=lambda x: x['A'] + x['B'])
)

    Point  interval   A   B  Returned_Data
0    11.5  (10, 20]  11  20             31
1    18.3  (10, 20]  11  20             31
2    31.3  (30, 40]  31  40             71
3    41.2  (40, 50]  41  50             91
4    51.5  (50, 60]  51  60            111
5    66.6  (60, 70]  61  70            131
6    34.7  (30, 40]  31  40             71
7    12.1  (10, 20]  11  20             31
8    14.4  (10, 20]  11  20             31
9    56.8  (50, 60]  51  60            111
10   54.3  (50, 60]  51  60            111
```

```py
In [5]: interval_ranges = [df['A'].iloc[0]] + df['B'].tolist()

In [6]: df.assign(interval=pd.cut(df['B'], interval_ranges))
Out[6]:
    A   B  interval
0   0  10   (0, 10]
1  11  20  (10, 20]
2  21  30  (20, 30]
3  31  40  (30, 40]
4  41  50  (40, 50]
5  51  60  (50, 60]
6  61  70  (60, 70]

In [7]: df2.assign(interval=pd.cut(df2['Point'], interval_ranges))
Out[7]:
    Point  interval
0    11.5  (10, 20]
1    18.3  (10, 20]
2    31.3  (30, 40]
3    41.2  (40, 50]
4    51.5  (50, 60]
5    66.6  (60, 70]
6    34.7  (30, 40]
7    12.1  (10, 20]
8    14.4  (10, 20]
9    56.8  (50, 60]
10   54.3  (50, 60]

In [8]: df2.assign(interval=pd.cut(df2['Point'], interval_ranges)).merge(df.assign(interval=pd.cut(df['B'], interval_r
     ...: anges)))
Out[183]:
    Point  interval   A   B
0    11.5  (10, 20]  11  20
1    18.3  (10, 20]  11  20
2    31.3  (30, 40]  31  40
3    41.2  (40, 50]  41  50
4    51.5  (50, 60]  51  60
5    66.6  (60, 70]  61  70
6    34.7  (30, 40]  31  40
7    12.1  (10, 20]  11  20
8    14.4  (10, 20]  11  20
9    56.8  (50, 60]  51  60
10   54.3  (50, 60]  51  60

In [9]: df2.assign(interval=pd.cut(df2['Point'], interval_ranges)).merge(df.assign(interval=pd.cut(df['B'], interval_r
     ...: anges))).assign(Returned_Data=lambda x: x['A'] + x['B'])
Out[184]:
    Point  interval   A   B  Returned_Data
0    11.5  (10, 20]  11  20             31
1    18.3  (10, 20]  11  20             31
2    31.3  (30, 40]  31  40             71
3    41.2  (40, 50]  41  50             91
4    51.5  (50, 60]  51  60            111
5    66.6  (60, 70]  61  70            131
6    34.7  (30, 40]  31  40             71
7    12.1  (10, 20]  11  20             31
8    14.4  (10, 20]  11  20             31
9    56.8  (50, 60]  51  60            111
10   54.3  (50, 60]  51  60            111
```

1. create the bins - `interval_ranges = [df['A'].iloc[0]] + df['B'].tolist()`
2. create your join column in both dfs using `pd.cut(df['B'], interval_ranges)` and `pd.cut(df2['Point'], interval_ranges)`
3. merge both dfs on this join column
4. create your `Returned_Data` column by adding the `A` and `B` columns
5. optionally drop the extra columns using `.drop(columns=['interval', 'A', 'B'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ReturnedData column **using the apply function** on df2 (aka points data frame) to fill its values based on each point.

**In the apply function, you should iterate on df (ranges) and check the condition**. if the point is in range, then return the sum of A and B.

The full code is like:

```
# init dataFrames

import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [0,11,21,31,41,51,61],
        'B': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]}

data2 = {'Point': [11.5, 18.3, 31.3, 41.2, 51.5, 66.6, 34.7, 12.1, 14.4, 56.8, 54.3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


# create a function to return the sum of A and B values if the point is between them
# input: point
# output: sum of the start and the of range if point is in range, otherwise returns None    
def fill_returned_data(point: float) -> float:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if point >= row['A'] and point <= row['B']:
            return row['A'] + row['B']
        
    return None

# create and fill ReturnedData column
df2['Returned_Data'] = df2['Point'].apply(lambda point: fill_returned_data(point))
df2.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df2
.conditional_join(
    df.astype(float).assign(a_b=df.sum(axis=1)), 
    ('Point','A','>='), 
    ('Point','B','<='), 
    df_columns='Point',
    right_columns='a_b')
) 
    Point  a_b
0    11.5   31
1    18.3   31
2    31.3   71
3    41.2   91
4    51.5  111
5    66.6  131
6    34.7   71
7    12.1   31
8    14.4   31
9    56.8  111
10   54.3  111
```